# Calculate difference between two datetimes if both present in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I currently have various time columns (DateTime format) in a pandas DataFrame, as shown below:

```
Entry Time          Exit Time
00:30:59.555        06:30:59.555
00:56:43.200        
10:30:30.500        11:30:30.500
```

I would like to return the difference between these times (Exit Time - Entry Time) in a new column in the dataframe if both Entry Time and Exit Time are present. Otherwise, I would like to skip the row, as shown below:

```
Entry Time          Exit Time          Time Difference
00:30:59.555        06:30:59.555       06:00:00.000
00:56:43.200        
10:30:30.500        12:00:30.500       01:30:00.000
```

I am fairly new to Python, so my apologies if this is an obvious question. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your dtypes are really datetime's then it's really simple:

```
In [36]:

df['Difference Time'] = df['Exit Time'] - df['Entry Time']
df
Out[36]:
                  Entry Time                  Exit Time  Difference Time
0 2014-08-01 00:30:59.555000 2014-08-01 06:30:59.555000         06:00:00
1 2014-08-01 00:56:43.200000                        NaT              NaT
2 2014-08-01 10:30:30.500000 2014-08-01 11:30:30.500000         01:00:00

[3 rows x 3 columns]
```

If they are not then you need to convert them using `pd.to_datetime` e.g.

```
df['Entry time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Entry Time'])
```

**EDIT**

There seems to be some additional weirdness with your data which I don't quite understand but the following seems to have worked for you:

```
df.dropna()['Exit_Time'] - df.dropna()['Entry_Time']
```

Comment: Ed - thanks for your response. This gets me close, but I still see values where exit time is not populated. Any thoughts on how I can skip those rows? Thanks again!

Comment: @wrcobb does the following work: `df.dropna()['Exit_Time'] - df.dropna()['Entry_Time']`?